# Plotting 3D bars in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

Why does the following happen when using `matplotlib` and `basemap` to plot a simple polygon collection and 3D bars. Using how it says to create these type of plots [here](http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basemap3d.html) one can create this sort of plot.

However, what's interesting is that if instead you do not zoom "all" the way in to focus on a specific set of bars they appear to be off-center although they aren't really. This results from the polygons being tilted and the bars remaining stationary I assume. Whenever tilting / rotating the plot the polygons will be moved to face over the bars and this is rather annoying as it ruins the look of the plot imo.

Does anyone know how to avoid this / fix this problem? I've included some sample images to describe this behavior.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the zorder of the Basemap.draw* calls?

Comment: I've tried playing around with the zorder some, but maybe I'm missing something. What would you suggest for adjusting the zorder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the best way to resolve this and if anyone has a better method please share.

I've found that a very simple way to get around the polygons going over the bars and creating this offset look is to simply make the polygon collection have a high transparency factor. Unfortunately, this also takes away the face color set to the polygons, and this is why I dislike this as a solution as you can no longer have a wide range of options manipulating the face / edge colors. The result is the following difference:

The bars i've created also have an `alpha` option set to `alpha = 0.5` that can of course be changed if anyone was wondering why they appeared to be so transparent.

Without manipulating the `alpha` option in a polygon collection such as the following

```
map = Basemap()
figure = plot.figure()
axes = Axes3D(figure)
for polygon in map.landpolygons:
    polygons.append(polygon.get_cords())
    #alpha = 0-1 in the below 1 highest 0 lowest
    collection = PolyCollection(polygons, closed = False)
axes.add_collection3d(collection)
```

results in the following

[image]

giving an alpha option of 0 in `collection = PolyCollection(polygons, alpha = 0, closed = False)` results in the following

[image]

As an interesting aside with an alpha option set to `alpha = 0.4` you can see where the polygons created start to overlap the bars

[image]